# How can I vectorize this numpy rotation code?

Tags: python, numpy

## The Goal:

I would like to vectorize (or otherwise speed up) this code.  It rotates a 3d `numpy` model around its center point (let x,y,z denote the dimensions; then we want to rotate around the z-axis).  The np model is binary voxels that are either "on" or "off"

I bet some basic matrix operation could do it, like take a layer and apply the rotation matrix to each element.  The only issue with that is decimals; where should I have the new value land since `cos(pi / 6) == sqrt(3) / 2`?

## The Code:

```
def rotate_model(m, theta):
    '''
        theta in degrees
    '''
    n           =np.zeros(m.shape)
    for i,layer in enumerate(m):
        rotated = rotate(layer,theta)
        n[i]    = rotated
    return n
```

where `rotate()` is:

```
def rotate(arr, theta):
    '''
        Rotates theta clockwise
        rotated.shape == arr.shape, unlike scipy.ndimage.rotate(), which inflates size and also does some strange mixing
    '''
    if theta == int(theta):
        theta *= pi / 180
    theta      = -theta
  # theta=-theta b/c clockwise.  Otherwise would default to counterclockwise
    rotated    =np.zeros(arr.shape)
    #print rotated.shape[0], rotated.shape[1]
    y_mid      = arr.shape[0]//2
    x_mid      = arr.shape[1]//2
    val        = 0
    for x_new in range(rotated.shape[1]):
        for y_new in range(rotated.shape[0]):
            x_centered = x_new - x_mid
            y_centered = y_new - y_mid
            x          = x_centered*cos(theta) - y_centered*sin(theta)
            y          = x_centered*sin(theta) + y_centered*cos(theta)
            x         += x_mid
            y         += y_mid
            x          = int(round(x)); y = int(round(y)) # cast so range() picks it up
            # lossy rotation
            if x in range(arr.shape[1]) and y in range(arr.shape[0]):
                val                   = arr[y,x]
                rotated[y_new,x_new]  = val
                #print val
                #print x,y
    return rotated
```

Comment: I just thought of something; if I try `scipy.ndimage.rotate()` on booleans, maybe they won't add like they did with numbers.  Confirming...

Comment: @AGNGazer I'm not 100% sure of the criteria for closing a question, but I'm asking for code.  I'm not asking "How do you convert between polar and Cartesian coordinates?" which would be a math question.  My question is extremely computational and practical in nature

Comment: You must understand that (in the general case) there is no way of rotating a bunch of pixels and have rotated coordinates be integers. So, then you need to "resample" your original image `I(i,j)` to a new grid `I(i',j')`. So, yeah, if it is OK for your problem - you can round to the nearest grid node. If you need to do better - use interpolation.

Comment: I misunderstood your question.

Answer (score 1):

You have a couple of problems in your code. First, if you want to fit the original image onto a rotated grid then you need a larger grid (usually). Alternatively, imagine a regular grid but the shape of your object - a rectangle - is rotated, thus becoming a "rhomb". It is obvious if you want to fit the entire rhomb - you need a larger output grid (array). On the other hand, you say in the code *"`rotated.shape == arr.shape`, unlike `scipy.ndimage.rotate()`, which inflates size"*. If that is the case, maybe you do not *want* to fit the entire object? So, maybe it is OK to do this: `rotated=np.zeros(arr.shape)`. But in general, yeah, one has to have a larger grid in order to fit the entire input image after it is rotated.

Another issue is angle conversion that you are doing:

```
if theta == int(theta):
    theta *= pi / 180
theta = -theta
```

Why??? What will happen when I want to rotate the image by 1 radian? Or 2 radians? Am I forbidden to use integer number of radians? I think you are trying to do too much in this function and therefore it will be very confusing to do use it. Just require the caller to convert angles to radians. Or, you can do it inside this function if input `theta` is *always* in degrees. Or, you can add another parameter called, e.g., `units` and caller could set it to `radians` or `degrees`. Don't try to guess it based on "integer-ness" of input!

Now, let's rewrite your code a little bit:

```
rotated = np.zeros_like(arr) # instead of np.zero(arr.shape)
y_mid = arr.shape[0] // 2
x_mid = arr.shape[1] // 2
# val = 0 <- this is unnecessary
# pre-compute cos(theta) and sin(theta):
cs = cos(theta)
sn = sin(theta)
for x_new in range(rotated.shape[1]):
    for y_new in range(rotated.shape[0]):
        x = int(round((x_new - x_mid) * cs - (y_new - y_mid) * sn + x_mid)
        y = int(round((x_new - x_mid) * sn - (y_new - y_mid) * cs + y_mid)
        # just use comparisons, don't search through many values!
        if 0 <= x < arr.shape[1] and 0 <= y < arr.shape[0]:
            rotated[y_new, x_new] = arr[y, x]
```

So, now I can see (more easily) that for each pixel from the *output* array is mapped to a location in the *input* array. Yes, you can vectorize this.

---

```
import numpy as np

def rotate(arr, theta, unit='rad'):
    # deal with theta units:
    if unit.startswith('deg'):
        theta = np.deg2rad(theta)

    # for convenience, store array size:
    ny, nx = arr.shape

    # generate arrays of indices and flatten them:
    y_new, x_new = np.indices(arr.shape)
    x_new = x_new.ravel()
    y_new = y_new.ravel()

    # compute center of the array:
    x0 = nx // 2
    y0 = ny // 2

    # compute old coordinates
    xc = x_new - x0
    yc = y_new - y0
    x = np.round(np.cos(theta) * xc - np.sin(theta) * yc + x0).astype(np.int)
    y = np.round(np.sin(theta) * xc - np.cos(theta) * yc + y0).astype(np.int)

    # main idea to deal with indices is to create a mask:
    mask = (x >= 0) & (x < nx) & (y >= 0) & (y < ny)

    # ... and then select only those coordinates (both in
    # input and "new" coordinates) that satisfy the above condition:
    x = x[mask]
    y = y[mask]
    x_new = x_new[mask]
    y_new = y_new[mask]

    # map input values to output pixels *only* for selected "good" pixels:
    rotated = np.zeros_like(arr)
    rotated[y_new, x_new] = arr[y, x]

    return rotated
```

Answer (score -1):

Here is some code for anyone also doing 3d modeling.  It solved my specific use-case pretty well.  Still figuring out how to rotate in the proper plane.  Hope it's helpful to you as well:

```
def rotate_model(m, theta):
    '''
        Redefines the prev 'rotate_model()' method
        theta has to be in degrees
    '''
    rotated = scipy.ndimage.rotate(m, theta, axes=(1,2))
    #       have tried (1,0), (2,0), and now (1,2)

    #                                               ^ z is "up" and "2"
    # scipy.ndimage.rotate() shrinks the model
    # TODO: regrow it back
    x_r     = rotated.shape[1]
    y_r     = rotated.shape[0]
    x_m     = m.shape[1]
    y_m     = m.shape[0]
    x_diff  = abs(x_r - x_m)
    y_diff  = abs(y_r - y_m)
    if   x_diff%2==0 and y_diff%2==0:
        return rotated[
            x_diff//2   : x_r-x_diff//2,
            y_diff//2   : y_r-y_diff//2,
                        :
        ]
    elif x_diff%2==0 and y_diff%2==1:
        # if this shift ends up turning the model to shit in a few iterations,
        # change the following lines to include a flag that alternates cutting off the top and bottom bits of the array
        return rotated[
            x_diff//2   : x_r-x_diff//2,
            y_diff//2+1 : y_r-y_diff//2,
                        :
        ]
    elif x_diff%2==1 and y_diff%2==0:
        return rotated[
            x_diff//2+1 : x_r-x_diff//2,
            y_diff//2   : y_r-y_diff//2,
                        :
        ]
    else:
        # x_diff%2==1 and y_diff%2==1:
        return rotated[
            x_diff//2+1 : x_r-x_diff//2,
            y_diff//2+1 : y_r-y_diff//2,
                        :
        ]
```